# How to add </div> at the end of the first <p>?

Tags: jquery, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm looking for a way to add `</div>` at the end of a first paragraph after a `<div>`. My problem is that I created an image block in ACF and I have a `<div>` to open the block. The output in the block looks like this:

```
<div id="side-image alignright">
   <div class="side-image alignright">
   [img]
   </div>
```

And the output on my website is this:

```
<div id="side-image alignright">
   <div class="side-image alignright">
   [img]
   </div>
   <p>text text text text</p>
   <p>text text text text</p>
   <p>text text text text</p>
   <p>text text text text</p>
   <p>text text text text</p>
```

What I'm trying to do is add a closing div () at the end of the first `<p>` after `<div class="side-image alignright">` so that it looks like this:

```
<div id="side-image alignright">
   <div class="side-image alignright">
   [img]
   </div>
   <p>text text text text</p>
</div>
<p>text text text text</p>
<p>text text text text</p>
<p>text text text text</p>
<p>text text text text</p>
```

I've tried `$( "#side-image p" ).first().append("</div>");` and that didn't work it. Any idea on what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:not` , `:first` and `insertAfter()` to achieve this .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("#side-image p:not(:first)").insertAfter('#side-image')
```

```css
#side-image {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="side-image">
  <div class="side-image alignright">
    [img]
  </div>
  <p>text text text text1</p>
  <p>text text text text2</p>
  <p>text text text text3</p>
  <p>text text text text4</p>
  <p>text text text text5</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand exactly what you wanted to do. As I understand it; You want the first **p** element to stay in **div**. You can do this as follows. I would be honored to help if you have any further questions. Best regards.

```js
var pItem = $('<p />').html('Text').appendTo($('.side-image'));

console.log($('#side-image-alignright').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="side-image-alignright">
    <div class="side-image alignright">
      [img]
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
</body>
```

To explain, we create a p element using jQuery. Then we append to the div.
For this, we use the function: `appendTo()`.